# Programming Wavelets for Audio Identification

Tags: audio, signal-processing

How exactly is a wavelet used digitally?

Wikipedia states

> "a wavelet could be created to have a frequency of Middle C and a
>   short duration of roughly a 32nd note"

Would this be a data structure holding e.g {sampleNumber, frequency} pairs?

If a wavelet is an array of these pairs, how is it applied to the audio data?

How does this wavelet apply to the analysis when using an FFT?

What is actually being compared to identify the signal?

Comment: This is not really a programming question, you could try http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like you've conflated a few different concepts here.  The first confusing part is this:

> Would this be a data structure holding e.g {sampleNumber, frequency} pairs?

It's a continuous function, so pick your favourite way of representing continuous functions in a discrete computer memory, and that might be a sensible way to represent it.

The wavelet is applied to the audio signal by convolution (this is actually the next paragraph in the Wikipedia article you referenced...), as is relatively standard in most DSP applications (particularly audio-based applications).  Wavelets are really just a particular kind of filter in the broader signal-processing sense, in that they have particular properties that are desirable in some applications, but they are still fundamentally just filters!

As for the comparison being performed - it's the presence or absence of a particular frequency in the input signal corresponding to the frequency (or frequencies) that the wavelet is designed to identify.